# Custom Chromium build - find registered extension's JS code

Tags: dll, dnspy

I have a custom chromium browser build which has a bunch of "native" functions which I would like to have definitions for.

Apparently, these are registered as en extension using this function: `Chromium.Remote.CfrRuntime.RegisterExtension(System.String,System.String,Chromium.Remote.CfrV8Handler)` which I was able to find in the ChromiumFX.dll.

I found this in the definition:

> "Register a new V8 extension with the specified JavaScript extension
> code and handler. Functions implemented by the handler are prototyped
> using the keyword 'native'. The calling of a native function is
> restricted to the scope in which the prototype of the native function
> is defined. This function may only be called on the render process
> main thread."

I'm a total reverse engineering noob so don't really know what I'm doing. I found the function using dnSpy but that's about it.

I tried looking into extracting the function definitions right from Chrome but apparently in the build they're using you can't do that. Or at least I couldn't find a way.

Is there a somewhat easy way of achieving what I want?